# Linux + convert single disk to two-disk RAID1 on Blade Server HS21

Tags: raid

My HS21 blade is configured with a single disk (Red Hat Enterprise Linux).

My goal is to add a second disk and reconfigure the disks to be mirrored.

How do I configure the blade server to be RAID1 without making any change on my disk. Does someone have a procedure or tool that can do this?

Comment: Backup, create RAID, restore. Done.

Comment: not sure because RAID sign   is inside the disk

Comment: What? Either you have a hardware RAID controller where you have to configure it in it's BIOS. Or you have a software RAID where you have to configure RAID levels in the management software. There is nothing "in the disk".

Comment: RAID0 with one disk... okay then.

Comment: please tell me if it possible -  I want to backup the original disk then perform RAID1 and then restore the original disk and add the second disk for mirroring , from my experience this isn’t possible , but I ask if you have some tricks or idea how to enable RAID1 in spite the restored disk have sign of RAID0

Answer (score 2):

The HS21 has an onboard RAID controller which if left unconfigured just passes through the disks to the OS. Don't call it RAID0.

Configuring this particular RAID controller for a mirror takes up a portion of the disk at the end for metadata, causing your disk size to shrink. If your partitions are configured so that you have some free space at the end of the disk you're in luck.

Otherwise: back up, perform the mirror and restore. Nothing will change except for the size of the disk.